# Не отображается страница 404 для несуществующего url

Tags: php, joomla, http-status-code-404

Есть сайт на *Joomla 2.5*. При таком запросе `http://odonts.biz/xxxxxxxxx` страница 404 отображается, но если ввести `http://odonts.biz/catalog/katalog-produktov/kassy/rijnvfrivn` то получаю белый экран.

Вот отчет об ошибках:

> Strict Standards: Non-static method JRegistryFormatINI::stringToObject() should not be called statically in /home/user1190020/www/odonts.biz/components/com_localcatalog/router.php on line 126
>   Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/user1190020/www/odonts.biz/plugins/system/modulesanywhere/modulesanywhere.php on line 47
>   Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/user1190020/www/odonts.biz/plugins/system/modulesanywhere/modulesanywhere.php on line 50
>   Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/user1190020/www/odonts.biz/plugins/system/modulesanywhere/modulesanywhere.php on line 83
>   Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/user1190020/www/odonts.biz/plugins/system/modulesanywhere/helper.php on line 51

Как это исправить? Сервер сообщает об ошибке 500.

Comment: возможно, установлено какое-то «расширение» для кастомной обработки 404-й ошибки, и оно работает некорректно.

Comment: А поставить в .htaccess редирект на 404 страницу это плохой тон, да?

Comment: а при каких условиях, по-вашему, должно происходить такое перенаправление?

Comment: Если мы знаем, что дальше /test/test2/catalog ничего не нет, то делаем редирект с директории catalog на 404. Это просто первое, что пришло в голову.

Comment: боюсь, вы собираетесь «поломать» всю работу вашего сайта. ведь она основана на том, что обращения к несуществующим файлам/каталогам перенаправляются в обращения к `/index.php`. посмотрите на «образцовый» файл `/.htaccess`: http://htaccess.ru/cms/joomla/

Answer (score 1):

У вас же написано, что вы вызываете нестатический метод как статический, чтобы это решить надо править исходники. Попробуйте обновить плагины и joomla